# WDK (Windows Driver Kit) and VC++ headers problem

Tags: visual-c++, usb, hid, wdk

I'm trying to read from an USB HID device, I know how to do it in C# using DLLImport hid.dll, but I want to do it from C++, this way I don't have to declare all the structures, etc, and just include the headers files.

So I downloaded the [WDK](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/ddk/winddk.mspx) and then when including the headers files and linking the libraries I'm getting a lot of errors:

```
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" {
    #include <hidsdi.h>
}

int main(){

}
```

Errors (6 out of 163):

```
Error   1   error C2065: 'PASSIVE_LEVEL' : undeclared identifier    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\hidpi.h  302 driver
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\hidpi.h  303 driver
Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'NTSTATUS'    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\hidpi.h  303 driver
Error   4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'  c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\hidpi.h  303 driver
Error   5   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\hidpi.h  303 driver
Error   6   error C2377: 'NTSTATUS' : redefinition; typedef cannot be overloaded with any other symbol  c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\hidpi.h  303 driver
```

OK so I read somewhere that I have to upgrade the Windows SDK too, I had the Microsoft Windows SDK v6.0A, I downloaded and installed the windows SDK v7.0. But then looks like I have two SDK now? How I properly do the SDK upgrade in visual studio?

I very much appreciate your help,

Thanks,
Carlos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution, don't know why this is working, but it is!:

In Visual Studio go to:

Tools->Options->Projects->VC++ Directories and then Show directories for: include files.

Add this folders:

C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk and C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\api

Now here is the trick that solved the problem for me and I don't know why, because seems odd but here it is:

C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk -> This directory have to be the first directory in the list!

C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\api -> This directory have to be ABOVE "$(WindowsSdkDir)\include" BUT BELOW "$(VCInstallDir)include"

Example:

```
C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk
$(VCInstallDir)include
$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include
C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\api
$(WindowsSdkDir)\include
$(FrameworkSDKDir)include
```

Carlos

Comment: The problem is, that the WDK and the SDK contain different header files, so that you have to force the WDK headers to be included first, for WDK header includes.

Comment: Do you remembered by any chance what have you used for lib ? Because it fails to link a function that I call from WDK. I added lib\win7\i386\ from WDK but apparently is not working

Comment: I just ran afoul of EXACTLY this issue.  THANK YOU!

Comment: run C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Setup\ WindowsSdkVer.exe and choose sdk 7.1