# Implement a small C DLL to interface between our C++ code and RawInput

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, joystick

After reading this Stack Overflow article,
[SlimDX: Joystick.Poll() succeeds on disconnected gamepad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619385/slimdx-joystick-poll-succeeds-on-disconnected-gamepad/12988935#12988935)

we decided to drop Windows 7 DirectInput altogether, and move to Windows 7 RawInput. We need to implement a small C DLL to interface between my C++ code and RawInput.

```
My sample C++ source code is,
// Adapters.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Adapters.h"

    extern "C" {
    #include "hidsdi.h"
    }

    #define MAX_GAMEPADS 32

    static TCHAR *deviceNames[MAX_GAMEPADS];
    static HANDLE deviceHandles[MAX_GAMEPADS];
    static UINT devicesActive;


    #define CHECK(exp)      { if(!(exp)) goto Error; }
    #define SAFE_FREE(p)    { if(p) { HeapFree(hHeap, 0, p); (p) = NULL; } }

    static BOOL ReadDeviceName(int index, HANDLE handle)
    {
        UINT size = 0;
        UINT result = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(handle,
            RIDI_DEVICENAME, NULL, &size);
        if (result != 0) {
            result = GetLastError();
            return false;
        }

        deviceNames[index] = (TCHAR *)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, size * sizeof(TCHAR));
        result = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(handle,
            RIDI_DEVICENAME, deviceNames[index], &size);
        if (result < 0) {
            result = GetLastError();
            HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, deviceNames[index]);
            deviceHandles[index] = NULL;
            deviceNames[index] = NULL;
            return false;
        }

        deviceHandles[index] = handle;
        return TRUE;
    }


    static BOOL ReadDeviceInfo(int index, HANDLE handle)
    {
        // May be a gamepad
        RID_DEVICE_INFO *info;

        UINT size = 0; // sizeof(RID_DEVICE_INFO);
        UINT result = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(handle, RIDI_DEVICEINFO,
            NULL, &size);

        info = (RID_DEVICE_INFO *) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, size);

        result = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(handle, RIDI_DEVICEINFO,
            info, &size);

        if (result != (UINT)-1) {
            if (info->hid.usUsagePage == 1 && 
            (info->hid.usUsage == 4 || info->hid.usUsage == 5))  {
                // It is a gamepad!!!

                HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, info);
                return ReadDeviceName(index, handle);;
            }
        } else {
            result = (UINT) GetLastError();
        }
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, info);
        return FALSE;
    }

    static int FindIndex(HANDLE handle)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_GAMEPADS; i++)
            if (deviceHandles[i] == handle)
                return i;

        return -1;
    }

    ADAPTERS_API int InitialiseGamepads(HWND handle)
    {
        RAWINPUTDEVICE devices[2];

        devices[0].usUsagePage = 1;
        devices[0].usUsage = 4; // Joystick
        devices[0].dwFlags = 0 ;
        devices[0].hwndTarget = handle;
        devices[1].usUsagePage = 1;
        devices[1].usUsage = 5;
        devices[1].dwFlags = 0 ;
        devices[1].hwndTarget = handle;

        bool result = RegisterRawInputDevices(devices, 2, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE));
        if (! result) {
            DWORD error = GetLastError();
            return 0;
        }

        UINT numdevices;
        GetRawInputDeviceList(NULL, &numdevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));
        RAWINPUTDEVICELIST *list = (RAWINPUTDEVICELIST *) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, 
            numdevices * sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));
        GetRawInputDeviceList(list, &numdevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));

        for(UINT i = 0; i < numdevices; i++) {
            if (list[i].dwType == RIM_TYPEHID) {
                if (ReadDeviceInfo(devicesActive, list[i].hDevice))
                    devicesActive++;
            }

        }

        return devicesActive;
    }

    ADAPTERS_API TCHAR *GetDevicePath(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= MAX_GAMEPADS)
            return NULL;

        return deviceNames[index];
    }


    ADAPTERS_API int PollDeviceChange()
    {
        // Read device list
        UINT numdevices;
        GetRawInputDeviceList(NULL, &numdevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));
        RAWINPUTDEVICELIST *list = (RAWINPUTDEVICELIST *) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, 
            numdevices * sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));
        GetRawInputDeviceList(list, &numdevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));

        BOOL found[MAX_GAMEPADS];
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_GAMEPADS; i++)
            found[i] = FALSE;

        for(UINT i = 0; i < numdevices; i++) {
            if (list[i].dwType == RIM_TYPEHID) {
                int index = FindIndex(list[i].hDevice);

                if (index >= 0)
                    found[index] = true;
                else {
                    // Find empty slot. Only process one change at a time, to simplify
                    // interface to managed code
                    for(int j = 0; j < MAX_GAMEPADS; j++)
                        if (! deviceNames[j]) {
                            if (ReadDeviceInfo(j, list[i].hDevice))
                                return j;
                        }
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_GAMEPADS; i++) {
            if (deviceNames[i] && ! found[i]) {
                // Missing device
                deviceHandles[i] = NULL;
                HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, deviceNames[i]);
                deviceNames[i] = NULL;
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    static void ParseRawInput(PRAWINPUT pRawInput,
        unsigned char *buttons, int *x, int *y)
    {
        PHIDP_PREPARSED_DATA pPreparsedData;
        HIDP_CAPS            Caps;
        PHIDP_BUTTON_CAPS    pButtonCaps;
        PHIDP_VALUE_CAPS     pValueCaps;
        USHORT               capsLength;
        UINT                 bufferSize;
        HANDLE               hHeap;
        ULONG                i, usageLength, value;

        pPreparsedData = NULL;
        pButtonCaps    = NULL;
        pValueCaps     = NULL;
        PUSAGE usages = NULL;
        hHeap          = GetProcessHeap();

        //
        // Get the preparsed data block
        //

        CHECK( GetRawInputDeviceInfo(pRawInput->header.hDevice, RIDI_PREPARSEDDATA, NULL, &bufferSize) == 0 );
        CHECK( pPreparsedData = (PHIDP_PREPARSED_DATA)HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, bufferSize) );
        CHECK( (int)GetRawInputDeviceInfo(pRawInput->header.hDevice, RIDI_PREPARSEDDATA, pPreparsedData, &bufferSize) >= 0 );

        //
        // Get the joystick's capabilities
        //

        // Button caps
        CHECK( HidP_GetCaps(pPreparsedData, &Caps) == HIDP_STATUS_SUCCESS )
        CHECK( pButtonCaps = (PHIDP_BUTTON_CAPS)HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, sizeof(HIDP_BUTTON_CAPS) * Caps.NumberInputButtonCaps) );

        capsLength = Caps.NumberInputButtonCaps;
        CHECK( HidP_GetButtonCaps(HidP_Input, pButtonCaps, &capsLength, pPreparsedData) == HIDP_STATUS_SUCCESS )
        int g_NumberOfButtons = pButtonCaps->Range.UsageMax - pButtonCaps->Range.UsageMin + 1;

        // Value caps
        CHECK( pValueCaps = (PHIDP_VALUE_CAPS)HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, sizeof(HIDP_VALUE_CAPS) * Caps.NumberInputValueCaps) );
        capsLength = Caps.NumberInputValueCaps;
        CHECK( HidP_GetValueCaps(HidP_Input, pValueCaps, &capsLength, pPreparsedData) == HIDP_STATUS_SUCCESS )

        //
        // Get the pressed buttons - only length required to tell if any are pressed
        //

        usageLength = HidP_MaxUsageListLength(HidP_Input, pButtonCaps->UsagePage, pPreparsedData);
        usages = (PUSAGE)HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, usageLength * sizeof(USAGE));
        CHECK(
            HidP_GetUsages(
                HidP_Input, pButtonCaps->UsagePage, 0, usages, &usageLength, pPreparsedData,
                (PCHAR)pRawInput->data.hid.bRawData, pRawInput->data.hid.dwSizeHid
            ) == HIDP_STATUS_SUCCESS );

        *buttons = (usageLength > 0);

        //
        // Get the state of discrete-valued-controls
        //

        for(i = 0; i < Caps.NumberInputValueCaps; i++)
        {
            CHECK(
                HidP_GetUsageValue(
                    HidP_Input, pValueCaps[i].UsagePage, 0, pValueCaps[i].Range.UsageMin, &value, pPreparsedData,
                    (PCHAR)pRawInput->data.hid.bRawData, pRawInput->data.hid.dwSizeHid
                ) == HIDP_STATUS_SUCCESS );

            switch(pValueCaps[i].Range.UsageMin)
            {
            case 0x30:  // X-axis
                *x = (LONG)value - 128;
                break;

            case 0x31:  // Y-axis
                *y = (LONG)value - 128;
                break;

            }
        }

        //
        // Clean up
        //

    Error:
        SAFE_FREE(pPreparsedData);
        SAFE_FREE(pButtonCaps);
        SAFE_FREE(pValueCaps);
        SAFE_FREE(usages);
    }

    ADAPTERS_API int ProcessInput(HANDLE wParam, HANDLE lParam, unsigned char *buttons, int *x, int *y)
    {
        UINT      bufferSize;

        GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, NULL, &bufferSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

        PRAWINPUT pRawInput = (PRAWINPUT)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, bufferSize);
        if(!pRawInput)
            return -1;

        GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, pRawInput, &bufferSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
        int index = FindIndex(pRawInput->header.hDevice);

        if (index < 0) {
            for(int j = 0; j < MAX_GAMEPADS; j++)
                if (! deviceNames[j]) {
                    if (ReadDeviceName(j, pRawInput->header.hDevice)) {
                        index = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }

        ParseRawInput(pRawInput, buttons, x, y);

        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pRawInput);


        return index;
    }
```

After unsuccesfully compiling the above sample C++ code and trying to link it in a Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 DLL project, I got some linker errors which refer to hdi library C functions. These are very puzzling to try to figure out the cause when I distictly remember adding hdi.lib and its'  path into the Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 DLL project linker dependencies. Could the problem be directly related to our extern C linkage of "hdisdi.h" in adapter.cpp? Also , please identify the exact include files and correct linker libraries we need to build the  Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 DLL project called Adapter?

Comment: What is the Vendor Id and Product ID for CH Products VM desktop joystick? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### With WDK 7, also  known as Windows 7 Raw Input HID API , the headers which come with the WDK are not compatible with those that come with Visual Studio.

USB HID API for Windows

Hello,

Last year I was doing some work with USB HID devices, and I was a bit frustrated by the difficulty of communicating with them using the Windows HID API (hid.dll). Best I could determine, the headers and import libraries for hid.dll do not exist within the Platform SDK, but only exist in the Windows Driver Kit (WDK). In the past, one could download the WDK and add it's include\ and lib\ paths to Visual Studio and be able to #include  and link with hid.lib and it would all work fine. This seemed to change, however, with the release of WDK 7.0.0.0. With WDK 7, the headers which come with the WDK are not compatible with those that come with Visual Studio.

One seems then to be left with a choice: either tell your Visual Studio project to ignore the standard include paths and use the WDK paths instead, or build a wrapper DLL using the WDK and link with it in your application (built using Visual Studio and the Platform SDK). I have done the latter and created HIDAPI (hidapi.dll). HIDAPI is a wrapper around the hidsdi.h system calls, and is built with the WDK. Any Windows executable can link to hidapi.dll without worrying about the platform SDK at all. It provides a clean interface suitable for doing what application developers need to do in order to communicate with USB HID Devices.

I did this last year, but finally got around to putting it up on GitHub and finishing the simple web page I put up for it just today.

To be clear, this is designed to be used from C and C++ applications running on Windows. I'd like to implement it also in Linux, providing a portable interface to HID devices.

The website for the project is located at:
   http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/

Please check it out and let me know if it's useful to you.

Alan.

---

I battled that all afternoon today. However, there is a possible solution to that:

HIDAPI can be downloaded from GitHub. A zip file is available from the Download Page. To get the latest trunk revision (if you have git installed, run the following:
   git clone git://github.com/signal11/hidapi.git
Build Instructions

Windows: 
Build the .sln file in the windows/ directory using Visual Studio.

Linux: 
Change to the linux/ directory and run make.

Mac OS X: 
Change to the mac/ directory and run make.

To build the Test GUI: 
On Windows, build the .sln file in the hidtest/ directory. Make sure to first set up the externals (Fox Toolkit) as described in README.txt.
On Linux and Mac, run make from the hidtest/ directory. Make sure to first install fox-toolkit as described in README.txt

Comment: I tested this with CH Products VM Desktop joystick.

Answer (score -1):

Good Morning, My answer to this Stack Overflow question is to read and apply the following URLS:

https://forum.pjrc.com/threads/24049-windows-dll-for-rawhid

[WDK (Windows Driver Kit) and VC++ headers problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337859/wdk-windows-driver-kit-and-vc-headers-problem)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/522a7180-c6aa-439f-963f-0ed10d49a239/how-do-i-use-wdk-with-visual-studio-2008?forum=vcgeneral

Thank you and Happy Holidays.

Comment: @Matt Ward, Could you please apply your expertise to this question?